# Combining entities with same name in cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

Im looking to combine entities from two columns which has same name.
Below is my dataset sample and I want just one node to be created and all relationships to be linked to this node.

```
Entity0      | Entity1    | Relationship | 
__________________________________________
Jamie Dimon  | Mit Romney  | friends
__________________________________________
Jamie Dimon  | Jamie Dimon | colleague
__________________________________________
Mason White  | Jamie Dimon | sibling
```

Using merge i could pick unique from each column and create 2 nodes for Jamie Dimon instead of 4 nodes. But I want just one node to be created for Jamie Dimon.

My query structure so far:

---

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:/final_neo4j.csv' AS line 
MERGE (e0:Entity0 {node: line.relation_first, name: line.entities_0_name, entity: line.entities_0_entity, confidence: toFloat(line.entities_0_confidence) }) 
WITH line, e0 
MERGE (e1:Entity1 {node: line.relation_second, name: line.entities_1_name, entity: line.entities_1_entity, confidence: toFloat(line.entities_1_confidence) })
WITH e0, e1, line 
MERGE (e0)-[r:Rel {name : line.relation_relation, confidence: toFloat(line.relation_confidence), url: line.url }]->(e1) 
RETURN e0,r,e1
```

Regards
Nrithya

Comment: Is there any reason you're using two different labels for your entities instead of just a a single :Entity label? If you only use a single label, and MERGE on a minimal set of properties that defines the entity, then you can avoid duplicates. Also, can you explain what the node, entity, and confidence properties are, and let us know which properties represent a unique :Entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, define a uniqueness constraint for the property that uniquely identifies an `Entity` node. Let's use `name`:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (e:Entity) ASSERT e.name IS UNIQUE;
```

This will create a schema constraint and ensure that no duplicate nodes can be added to the database (as defined by two nodes with the label `Entity` that have the same value for the property `name`).

Then, when you `MERGE` only merge on that property and `SET` properties after the `MERGE`:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:/final_neo4j.csv' AS line 
MERGE (e0:Entity {name: line.Entity0})
ON CREATE SET e0.confidence = toFloat(line.entities_0_confidence)
MERGE (e1:Entity {name: line.Entity1})
ON CREATE SET e1.confidence = toFloat(line.entities_1_confidence)
MERGE (e0)-[r:REL {name:line.Relationship]->(e1)
RETURN *
```

Comment: It may also be useful to consider the [addLabels()](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_creating_data) function of APOC Procedures, if you want to use the relationship in the CSV for the relationship type instead of for the name property of the very generic :REL relationship type.